# Is it possible to hold or delay document.ready execution for sometime?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using `jQuery version: 2.2.4`

I want to know that is it possible to delay `document.ready` execution for sometime or any specific time. I know that after `document.ready` we can use `setTimeout` function. But I want to know any better way to do this.

Any reference will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why. Please let us know so we can give better answers. Right now it sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through the jQuery API from beginning to end. It only takes about an hour or two, and pays for itself in saved time almost immediately. Or even just going to http://api.jquery.com and searching for the thing you're curious about (such as "ready").

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with [`jQuery.holdReady`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/):

> Description: Holds or releases the execution of jQuery's `ready` event.

```
// Start holding
jQuery.holdReady(true);

// ...later, when you want to stop holding (perhaps after a timer delay)...
jQuery.holdReady(false);
```